# How to redirect stdin/stdout/stderr when replacing process using os.execl

Tags: python, pycharm, os.execl

Consider the following sample script:

```
import os
import sys

print(1)
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, '-c', 'print(2)')
print(3)
```

The result is

```
1
```

I was expecting

```
1
2
```

I think it is because the replacing process is not using the same stdin/stdout/stderr?

How can I achieve what I was expecting for while using `execl`?

I'm using Python 3.6 on Windows.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.6.2 on windows 10. Simply the `2` comes after the cmd prompt.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, Thanks! I was running the script in PyCharm and, for some reason, it does not print the `2`. When I ran it from the command prompt it works. Stupid, I know. (^_^;)

Comment: I have created a bug report on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27648 (Unfortunately, I cannot delete this question in the bounty period.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug about PyCharm as I cannot reproduce it with IDEA too. IDEA is using the same core as PyCharm using.

This is because of the way you launch your script. If you launch your script with `Run`, it works. If you launch it with `Debug`, it doesn't.

Because `Run` just run script in a terminal, but `Debug` will launch a debugger and connect that process to this debugger. The output you see is actually from debugger but not directly from your script. When you replace your process, debugger won't rebuild connection to that new-created process.

That's why you didn't get `2` outputted.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but I'm positive that I'm using `Run`, not `Debug`.

Comment: I have tested it again with pycharm 2017.3 on ubuntu 16.04. It behaves like I described above. `Run` works but not `Debug`.

Comment: Just curious, are you using Python 3.6, too? I've heard that PyCharm uses a different [debugging infrastructure for 3.6](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/03/pycharm-2017-1/), maybe the test runner has been rewritten, too?

Answer (score 1):

In Linux,there is a flag `FD_CLOEXEC`,you can test it by `fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout,fcntl.F_GETFD)`

the behavior you described can reproduce in ubuntu16 by

```
import os
import sys
import fcntl
print(1)
ret = fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout, fcntl.F_GETFD)
ret |= fcntl.FD_CLOEXEC
fcntl.fcntl(sys.stdout, fcntl.F_SETFD, ret)
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, '-c', 'print(2)')
print(3)
```

So when you run in PyCharm,it must redirect the stdout and set the equivalent windows flag.

Comment: op is using PyCharm in windows, which does not have `fcntl` interface.